# passing PHP variables across javascript windows.open to another PHP page

Tags: php, javascript, window.open

I have a PHP page `index.php` contains javascript window.open code to make another page `create_pdf.php` popup and pass some PHP variables to it to create a pdf file using [FPDF](http://fpdf.org/)

Here is my variables:

```
$text1 = "this is text1";
$text2 = "this is text2";
```

And here is FPDF code in the `http://mysite.com/create_pdf.php` page, which I need to pass PHP variables $text1 and $text2 to it from index.php page:

```
require('fpdf.php');
$pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
$pdf->Cell(40, 10, $text1);
$pdf->ln();
$pdf->Cell(40,10, $text2);
$pdf->Output();
```

And here is the PHP variable `$pdf_link` which contains javascript window.open code:

```
$pdf_link = "<div class=\"pdf-box\"><a target=\"_blank\"  
onclick=\"return !window.open(this.href, 'pdf', 'width=640,height=300')\" 
href=\"http://mysite.com/create_pdf.php\"; 
return false;\">Create pdf</a></div>";
```

Exactly what I need is how can I edit the variable `$pdf_link` in `index.php` so I can Pass $text1 and $text2 or any number of variables to `create_pdf.php` page.

**Note**: I'm familiar with PHP but not familiar with Javascript.

Comment: Just thought I should link my "duplicate post", the question is the same, but much simpler context IMO. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42498574/php-pass-variable-to-new-window-open-javascript/42498745#42498745

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I am following but you might want to try:

```
$pdf_link = "<div class=\"pdf-box\"><a target=\"_blank\"  
onclick=\"return !window.open(this.href, 'pdf', 'width=640,height=300')\" 
href=\"http://mysite.com/create_pdf.php?text1=" . urlencode($text1)  .  "&text2=" . urlencode($text2)  .  "\"; 
return false;\">Create pdf</a></div>";
```

or

```
$fullLinkWithParams = urlencode("http://mysite.com/create_pdf.php?text1=" . $text1  .  "&text2=" . $text2);

$pdf_link = "<div class=\"pdf-box\"><a target=\"_blank\"  
onclick=\"return !window.open('" . $fullLinkWithParams  .  "', 'pdf', 'width=640,height=300')\">Create pdf</a></div>"
```

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply, What about if I can't use global variable or the $text1 was very long text?

Comment: He actually probably needs a mix of the two. Probably will want to add teh full URL with query string to both the window.open() parameter as well as the href property of the `<a>` (for case where javascript is not enabled. You also need to `urlencode()` the value.  I will edit answer for you...