# Security Issue on Accessing Remote Image with dompdf

Tags: php, dompdf

I am using dompdf to generate PDF file which is getting some images (Dynamic charts)  from highcharts.js exporting library. Now I have to change the default setting of DOMPDF_ENABLE_REMOTE from "false" to "true" to enable dompdf the inclusion of images from remote sites. I just noticed that enabling this feature can cause security issues for my server, now my question is how bad this issue might be and how I can prevent those thing? Is there any other extra setting which I can use to stop security risk besides having access to remote resources(in this case images) ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enabling remote access is mainly a security issue when you're using dompdf.php to render your documents. If you're not using that file you should remove it or make it inaccessible from the web. The dompdf team generally recommends that you not use that file and instead write your own PDF generation script using the dompdf class directly. Once you're using the class directly you can further protect yourself by placing the entire dompdf directory in a location not accessible via the web.

The main concern when enabling remote resource access and when using dompdf.php to render documents is that someone can use dompdf.php to load a document from outside your domain that appears to by something produced and served by your domain. However, there is further concern if you also have PHP parsing enabled (for inline scripting). With PHP parsing enabled the remote document can be further used to compromise your machine via remote code execution (inline script is not limited to PDF interaction).

Comment: Thanks  Brian, this was helpful but can you please let me know what do you mean exactly by "The dompdf team generally recommends that you not use that file and instead write your own PDF generation script using the dompdf class directly." can you please let me know how I can have such a file? I mean , is there any sample to show how to use dompdf with our own classes?

Comment: The exact steps you would use depends on your situation, but implementing the class only takes a few lines of code, see https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/wiki/Usage#using-the-dompdf-class-directly.

Answer (score 0):

An option is use Base64 image data

```
$html = '<div>
    <p>IMAGE</p>
    <img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAMgAAABMCAIAAACnG28HAAAABmJLR0QA/wD/AP%2BgvaeTAAAACXBIWXMAAAsTAAALEwEAmpwYAAAAB3RJTUUH1AgeBS42B7vBqgAAEhBJREFUeNrtnd%2BPHEcVhfcfBoknxAOIh0g88EsIIqKI1UprObYVe23FwQmskO0EYSskkCgkEo5MCMgoGBABhBDkIXzV3%2Byh6Onu6ZnZ2Zm1u1Qa9fb0VFfdOvfcW7du9%2B59NpWpbKDsTSKYygSsqUzAmsoErKlMZQLWVDZeHj3%2B67vvf/DSjZcODy/%2B9N5bH374O85MwJrKWpACT/vPfe%2B5Z5/97re/8cxXv/L1rz3DwcEPngdhS8FrAtZUZgWWuvHiJcBkBVugivrlL30RbB0eHLx5784ErKksUWCj6zd/DHqAEZD6wuc/x8GNo6uvvnLLPwGZZnEC1lSWsH1CSnKyiq3LV657Ust45dLFCVhTGVXACoiJOyWe8LHEmSdfu3NbK7krphBtgDzp0zR/uynSt3/xJl65AKLKVaDq4YN3WQny%2Bdrxy5cv7MNb1KXs4AaBRc/UhqX4cyrDnhCOjjhgptfHKI3IVVR569Wb1/78x0f1ZWCL88BrKbraFLAgT/CkNkzAOi2uCqqs6/AWremtp7Log8D%2B/emnrSvhLSC1LKo2AixFoD8ItQIv2GtCxvp0VTvXiHcdqbLcC6RwzJkjUTUPLI1Pi8a2Ayw6gaMXKbBqBfUTMtYsPzq%2BG08IF3sdYIFRHCmNIKjieAVC2gKwGLBeocCi6whlQsb6RkBPKLGAldUV10qMGlXHi9pEn08fWFAUfhXunr0HYRDYClw6lRpYiLQ2hQh22WVaC6OGFZisDU3N6QMLDaC7ki0uIeZ8ijisDyzE6GIo2GKFtEJT%2BOz8lnZ0rTbnpZw%2BsDDYAAvG0n%2BffKz1S4lPHl3Vu8AOruy8S1dx/7Ekm%2BvzBhjrzu2oFxXSegrtIFNo8slptebGi8DSxwJYnYu44RWAnKd3hSt8noDFgI3YylhQ7kYHsGvUgutDRbtgbkTBGfVqHe0CWDAWKiosXBsuuySiJ86IaTBM0EYVfm8Twi2kdfOaw8DZWs0bOHcFGDHZKBKONkNGnUAYxyCM84hFyawWJsAIACwhlbSWpRKkErsCVTS1ocXgqQELYSFBPiMvIEXFfkvd5og9DVwFaJgwgcUB3gxjRxRMP9gqJw8vMrsYtWUTMrkeaBp5j/PO8XjKYXYuX7lOf6iJiO4osPQhkKYsTeVPrD49dksnOWJPPGMxcGadITNnVNDDkJMj4CauAikr5cOLLM24YAy83B%2BkmsHilk4ChOPJL0FRezhgB51WWrZ6Jp/1ZacMLG9MR8ETyocmISM6ypgRKF3hJFUfa6nxOxJNhgdb9LuXWqww8abzFhAcHMBS2kGEAHPzybclntdooJeBswHOkKLkmGRyBlL672XP%2BJVb4912usHd458AbmuSF6ia8mxH6iLzSTf4oV2iemD/6Wrn/O6toJ2aOW42k2YjShMZEFlR2ZvXSip%2B42xyfgxEVPE4Afyc1pbNs14fUnT14YN3A%2B5RJubCPl1ljvkEOoh7ngw4w/lco6D6RqdyImQFIra0X5wxpZPKwch4AQ26Tk%2BSTNDZqn3n/cpbJ0Ir9eqxzQ95OWDRxYLxkxVftgXMkPFYgDsGBIFAF4JDolYvNRY2qM%2B7vp1a2AEukGPMduKTP8cAy0cP6HCBQoOqgYsLtnBAGzeLWl9cBw6iVCYg6E4IMs4HWMhqpHAYSCDVh5sxNZAKn4FsRsQ6YHVgaafqXAvgRaOCLGk9iQ4HeXDmwhminYAy9IsetKS/Ylzt%2BGUmfrgPBggcnQZoTGobfXOMdBgRj4kDF5f0xUsynG6WOQUCywi7Bitg0k%2BP255pljMWylbrNkBFnYyV9UFCskJKh0fLiCIxlr4O7I20EfRP60brrf1wBCq8vHEQrX5wfnjxwvSE8OpURj3NdRx/WgYfwEUPuk8E6gw3MrPbboxZc%2Bity1gjyYMuCSyxVQMr6Ubqlaprl2orlulX2n3oT%2BxjmH4SFcs%2BT3ysaHgsieRE/0NRAzO7N9Ka6HUiRK1bJ%2Bu4qVlvaTEA/hy4vaE/fbUAK7lc8lbfnA0YOL9i8kLdzGIf%2Bem0mk4pT4iVYcZKvNHJGOkL0gfDEGipZldUgQOjCXmmTzAhVfQWAcZbiGAV1HwnvUWfI1VvCgliJOyQuZ0ROHBDhTtoiurBsvtyeyPpKls0A7k76mISHR0DEhzYeWC%2BXf3q9TMeBpDgqiOHctTs1rwCBaQwj1o1lftGv3XXOkPVZpGrM67gCsM3JC%2Bj9PWc66P3/HykuPWf4u%2B7LcNYolc6UjTeyhLWSuq81wZrHlj0vH7YZp6iTGwPdBC4Se6nG4jfGxWaO7H6w8sQembcIT4BUkBMfTYIgSrEJFwLIG1riQ438TANTQ0soVPWI4cXW0B3kW/QSAIID80nSZs6xmQbfNLvKUGBJm7E%2Bb6eM1K9n9Dh2AX10VUDyPGxuIU%2BUFZCfQnmDM2u1gvDeXut6aj99NrpLl7Bhf0zSAtYzFiJrTGRCy9m%2BhlqGMsVYqezopSpSopZj8YgVnEgjZkqGF%2BEmYhj28pTM28JROpdImLuwidnuFErJmlwAQCpNgafjAWI2oGlg3ZwZqxHeNAWqJfGaZYBIlVm1ycaYvcl74GbcnHNQ/M7hsgQgegDBHy6xdK/wD2D2M3eMF0Z%2BdXej0lgldjVmFnc%2BcJ%2BJ7CQiHbdAbccqZJ700TLbIc%2BIDKBRZc8qRaGROP8JhjGDHEXLqDyFcdxlrkdf7oE0wjSfon33LwmNAV93xzbtxmLH10dE84w5KPCcGujMHw6Rs3TcNRUz8Gn/5KhAExb14BXuuQ1RmWZAsMis0SmTWbLjAKWCyUty8g9y%2BL6Nb/SXTDKPG8p9FXjqM5fYOK8sFPiwUSdsl2LyTBB%2BEb3qzAWNq4Ji3ClJpW7a%2B9KmKBZOkiW5mX4fJGbfX3%2BuxbfaOcYYKlsVCOfCTQUvT04CLWDieFMGDPfW4v/vvCNN9KdUM7zHL8FYM3oCt1F40cn67nPkzBptjJi5lrgKM9Ddpn8YlKPX3YdpDjyGEnCE9ISkhVAQiE7/16vz6TLrGlzf9OMA7uXuxsf575uJIubedAYbRf0C/dVwlXJpzXBQUPM%2BcT/Mt8D2DL/s14YdmYlMZCEA9x%2BVoddIpzN1u3egGuFFAqRsvgah3F3LeQS5WgkpvafamA5VC7rbM0ncd3ZqJdIkpCkqF4ar6LGC6bb3ggACQK7YdTbQRkkaw2Nm2o15C1JrtUx2oz2c%2BVAVMLN6YQP1KJoiLLStVqouuq5tJegA8clTD2IbLfgEhJDOGeTHrc3HCPWYI3xrspyrPFD9cQ17fEW494qU9lCJ4wr%2B1ZeXIaO8ll7x3r9%2BkbaIykhe5dBYRaYTqr%2BU1ntN6gquwJzm/wGO0r/T%2BLjncAKgnXd%2BhxtWVkfDgRrlAWWK2i9BaNHC%2BOIrhaTOaLrSUUaA6sH7b6rb0e9ZWDp9srhC7tiKpIKoVK6wgqw9B7qELPIkDY6H5XkJ1HomhXcUpXJZslPjc8emqxVX7eJani9cFvjHrlQ6iQJJs98Ms1Wa6u4LLuaZW/SBFrus8sCjY6m1uWLNSrqKwjUDUfR56gZ8TGU6Ps53EuVvdSBAdbUjMSdXee5sdMBFjSQVdsAY%2BmySFEGymfT2Tg38YSCnpnvfLKtUczcyc5Gi64Uh3vSLaGL2gA3gdAS15kzbcWkNvgwwm7OxfyVLRNsCqjOQEhLdPpkW%2BJkIs8tFLXFITt2ac90j1o/pcawKVci8M5sC8677SEEdf%2BL2jdRXBclA7FcA3XZh90ysLTojFzvpLZl2Ycya0Kzkuf/Y1nqxUhc7HjfmhsbT4ZgeEtcZs9h3lYmcFrvznaaNt%2BaYgJnsppokzN9gWaBZbw0mTBJLEYstY8l6MNhMTeJoRfao7Vml62tkM2TATOfr0GYgdmkScnrehQ2aMTcZY2LviTh9FlDlbAG1jZNoeKT0rPg15thwFKFU5X95pbgijfQCE49Q76xhrNlQWPLdD%2BNMKn3Sjy8zQXzInNhmFBWNs46sWJ%2BFX3OLiRtDguFn8y8sWaHx/18408mQWjCXM0Z6w%2BHJS1OMvaNGvMkobdk1fKaEpP9YF0ILZ0%2BiUEfV3yCVehnd6jTTy2W/YT7Hf42gaWW64zXxF7vtCdVpnMDUV9EWjLiYAacjCWN%2B21B6ouXCi9euY4IkpI6sHuvnxGuEit99lr%2By17nsGWv49euSSWtbPjotImA2YMJTQA5cTW9LgMcbn32EYlEWGxis1Zl4EJZUIokCYnPFsVKq2aBa4s7TaGzEGLTnm7Zx8quZ5IY67fehPMHNp7UlfrJVYGl7chDrUJqFoY9ySM1ublvIS1jOZ3GlwcCImptYuUjQycMKhPPb%2BlPFm609r9XvjZ%2BNOThOlHJFG%2B9mfWBbV3xBJhMBcvuoV6dPCSk%2Bp6oCefp2psU2eItlcoFPkNQu7a8KtQqaQVmWUcnK/zZY/%2BL3h0oM%2Bmc%2BvM6yCn/S/KumRNechEwMH4DV/bBXaPhnXlR4n7%2ByD18hu/mvxsv9DZzxu2yVhBJySQ2rDCSEvQWXCrWXp0UyHmaNW1maJHRtFCEeXQVbLUuFlh5Rmj7prAm0iAgzwUMjLaTWuoHDF0AhrRUUF14HVWnanjwyqt4xE2Ec2RnVkgL6Uxniyl0R8V8qQS7l21/9lLGhqv09JMOZcvDChMfrk9t3PBOFslOAKveHzBfZ1nZmTCZJz2SgWToUt/CBZGU5kpnx1/URs/jC%2BPIn8rTRAh2IYwG%2BtM3NbNNqsbZjU%2B8ibdhrQKsNeXlO0KCmzqyYMRSnVstTXGLwNLp3PG3f81sTpPEoU%2B88mtqdgtYWWGZI%2BourJ6m/6Tls3NYDN9nM3TH30yBxuq2J8D2JDBW7cW7gNLY%2ByjiOX0LjY5jWf1duT7m2bKt9zbeyCzi%2BGQwVgxicjtdBJ3Tl2aVvaYmJd8IPmSw46%2BVE1h5%2Bqi8FXbriX6nji3reX%2BJcr1d2PmczA7yax58op7NC9Knf3myuo8lsOY3j7dV/vaX33eqgYHuAGv7Oe%2BbLv9pyjmC1L/%2B8fizk3wBfWEfpdTN%2BvV7b3gZB1QvbhXO//bhr6he/M5br99//ZiDV2/d%2BuFLR9Y7xzdblZNewDHXW/ktP/T47u2fcMy3nrHlAEsfK9aQP89A7Htno0ZKWYkzZgSBmC6/UNwuKsdKCol//OjhhvQ4srYznPcr7uhNc96Tdphf%2BUOmzQ7X%2BfjuRzF53/nWN1t1//nvOzqrZ6jzV/pV5/lTqebz5Mk8jsWroIxknJ3UWv9XARaT6nTWRNqpbZ18GwWKxuSgFmuT13dQiy9S7pQp1zuLN66%2BoAjqe1Gjzd6OUXBlKj8cnsXWtxx7uzETbHCIAZl6kMwCSOXo2g3asTJeqs36Z0TBZV55fHzbevfuz/ikEQ6ohRffef/%2BvfvUN37%2BNn%2B%2B994DD7wsLdgsB/xJB%2BoGvSxvXM7CsESk9/9vUjpHna9ovJatxCnXRlfn6WCvT3y06KS2MMTJ8WrnADJmRqt0WgWp/eajj5WmIuYnSyklN6qPlbhC8e7MEI1zd9oXAV7g9NfVn1jpCT9Jn%2Bkk1ciccSwfIm2FsmLic/DJ3/9JzQUcO941WYFf1c32LTWSXG%2B4QR/rwQcfRfKP//TJoz885jjIZuCZMpCEKLQwHMi%2BfVUuoBZgpRO0wgTQHE0MTyRTwj1UC7tIz2yEA8/U8lrTqNMglQkGHAqCT44Ljf/yHaXDBc5WLeu%2B%2B7bmtXVmeLZkLJPJ9F12/JWFyZrMI0wLF%2Ba13BR%2BJhdBCUFORlelTzVWftlbKHd/Xxjr3n0xvlD0T3zx8cPkbox/GHpry9iT51zM7dloEFHkTeGG1UNZeQ7Ct07sbG/zTpe8nOgMgroTsFYpeSWOby7Z8ZCvGbnZK5yAtdPAmqV9jk5N22LxscRkZpfHIauHhH0v5gSsXSlmUJ2L7Skjunn/Vt447MtRzKKegDWVVTzCkpJ1eDGvfjRb32f4NmTKJ2A9FcWnhvKWnrwrS4RtYh99AtZTUcqLSU8eAa/fpy17TYw1ldWtoW5W3ouc9yX3vZRlAtZUFhcfi8q/PMlrz/2/hxOwprKWNfTB2sTfh9%2BBPQFrKmOtoU/x5%2BVQG32qYgLW00Va/vcb/z3nRu81AevpKr5tYPi9EhOwprK7ZQLWVCZgTeX8lP8CuDenorrKqfIAAAAASUVORK5CYII%3D">
</div>':

require_once('dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php');
$dompdf = new DOMPDF ();
$dompdf->load_html ($html);
$dompdf->render ();
$dompdf->stream ("Test.pdf", array ("Attachment" => false));
```

Get the image from php in base64:

```
//getIMG.php?data=1&id=123
if ($data == 1) {
    echo "data:image/".$adj->type.";base64,"
            .str_replace ("\n", "", base64_encode ($adj->imageBinary));
}
```